# How to plot differences in colour in R (or other software)?

Tags: r

I have three colour values I want to compare in a plot to visualize which one is more blue than the others. The values are in CIELab (which can be converted to sRGB, but afaik CIELab is more precise). I have some experience using R (but not a lot), if there's some other type of software I can use for this purpose I would be happy to try it out.

The values in question:

Sample #1: 26.85/42.94/16.45

Sample #2: 31.92/41.50/12.12

Sample #3: 26.97/38.97/14.41

Comment: So you want to plot these values for their location in CIE color space and/or sRGB or some other color space?  Does your visualization have to be 2d?  After all, with RGB you already have a 3d coordinate system. :)

Comment: Yes, I want to plot these values as their location in (preferentially) CIELab colour space or in sRGB colour space.